# Looker Map / Store Points and Sales Heat Map in one dashboard

Tags: looker

I have a straightforward question, how to show in a **SINGLE** map:

- Store locations (I have Lat/Long)
- As dots on the map Sales (I have Lat/Long) - As HeatMap

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this, as a workaround I used just the sales long/lats and used the store names as dimensions. This allows you to cluster the sales by store where the dots on the map are coloured by store, even if the store 'pins' themselves are absent.

So in Looker terms: Sales (long/lat) as Dimension, Store Name as pivot and Sales as measure.